Laravel 11 Bitbucket pipelines configuration
We had a working build pipeline in Bitbucket until our recent Laravel 11 upgrade, and now it is unable to find the mysql driver to connect to the DB.  Here is the error when running migrations/tests:
In Connection.php line 825:                                                                           
  could not find driver (Connection: mysql, SQL: select exists (select 1 from  
   information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'homestead' and table_name   
  = 'migrations' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED')) as `ex  
  ists`)                                                                       
                                                                          
In Connector.php line 66:              
  could not find driver

Here was our working (L9-10) bitbucket-pipelines.yml:
image: php:8.2-fpm

definitions:
  services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:8.0
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'homestead'
        MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        MYSQL_USER: 'homestead'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'secret'
  steps:
    - step: &install-dependencies
        name: Setup
        caches:
          - composer
          - node
        script:
          - docker-php-ext-install pcntl
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -qy git curl unzip
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer install --no-progress --no-scripts
          - curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
          - apt-get install -y nodejs
          - npm i --no-progress
          - npm run build
        artifacts:
          - vendor/**
          - node_modules/**
          - public/**
  .scripts:
    - &setup-tests |
        apt-get update && apt-get install -qy libmcrypt-dev default-mysql-client
        echo "memory_limit = 256M" > $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini
        cp .env.pipelines .env
        php artisan key:generate
        php artisan storage:link

pipelines:
  # default pipeline
  branches:
    '{develop,staging,master}':
      - step: *install-dependencies
      - parallel:
        - step:
            name: Unit
            script:
              - *setup-tests
              - php artisan test tests/Unit
            services:
              - mysql
        - step:
            name: Feature
            script:
              - *setup-tests
              - php artisan test tests/Feature
            services:
              - mysql


I am able to run tests locally using the mysql driver, so it seems like there's an extension we're missing in the image.

Fixed by adding docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql to the setup-tests script.
